# See git server messages in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket-server

How can I get IntelliJ IDEA to display (git) server messages?

I'm using

- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5
- Atlassian Connector for IntelliJ IDE 3.0.16
- git 2.5.1
- Atlassian Stash 3.11.0

Our git server is configured to occasionally display messages that the user should read. For example, the response to a `git push` includes a message such as:

`remote: Create pull request for 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
remote:   https://stash.example.com/projects/group/repos/proj/compare/commits?sourceBranch=refs/heads/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
remote:`

The use then can hit the given URL to get to the "Create Pull Request" page in Stash, saving a little time and a modicum of frustration and confusion.

But all I see in IDEA's Event Log is

`12:33:52 PM 1 file committed: (Comment)
12:33:54 PM Push successful: Pushed 1 commit to origin/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Is the "remote:" message logged somewhere else? Is there a setting I can tweak?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found it: Version Control Console:

- little button far lower left (looks like a frame of movie film to me!) [image: the button]
- **Version Control** [image: the menu]
- **Console** tab [image: the tab bar]